# Try-except or Exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I'm new to programming and am struggling to get my Try-except function to work.
I want the user to be able to only write a number using digits and when they type in a letter or symbol I want the except statement to start.
How should I do?
Thank you very much!

```
while True:
  try:
    x = int(input("Please write your phone number to receive a confirmation: "))
     
  except: 
    print("Obs!")
    break
    
print("You did not write a real number : {0}".format(x))
print("No symbols or letters allowed!!")
```

Comment: When I run the program and write down a number with a letter in it I only get an error. I want it to print what's written in the prints and then give the user a second chance to write the correct number.

Answer (score 2):

You want to put all of those warning prints in the exception handler. And assuming you want to keep prompting until a number is entered, do the `break` after the successful conversion.

When `int` fails, the assignment to `x` is skipped and its value is not available in the exception. Since you want to echo wrong choices back to the user, save the text value to an intermediate variable.

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = input("Please write your phone number to receive a confirmation: ")
        x = int(answer)
        break
     
    except ValueError: 
        print("Obs!")    
        print("You did not write a real number : {0}".format(answer))
        print("No symbols or letters allowed!!")
```

Comment: ohhh now I got it! I tried to follow the videos on my course-page and they put the warning prints outside the exception handler and used the int(input()). This makes more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

No need to use try/except statements. A more pythonic way to do it is to simply wrap it in a while statement and use x.isnumeric(). The benefit of this is that you can continue execution afterwards

```
done = False

while not done:
    x = input('Please write your phone number to receive a confirmation: ')

    if x.isnumeric():
        done = True
        x = int(x)
    else:
        print("Obs!")    
        print("You did not write a real number : {0}".format(x))
        print("No symbols or letters allowed!!")
# anything else here
```

Why would you want negative numbers??? It’s a phone number, and with my solution, you can easily edit it and add conditions. try/except should be a fallback, not a default.

Comment: Better to let `int` raise an exception than reimplement all the checks it's going to make for you. Consider, `"-3".isnumeric()` returns `False`, despite `-3` being a perfectly valid integer.